# AWS - Unable to access console - Not receiving MFA SMS codes

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

I am receiving SMS messages from other senders.

However, I am not receiving any SMS codes when I try to login to the AWS console and it indicates that it is sending them to me.

There is no AWS support I can find without logging in.  Without the SMS, I am unable to login.

How to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a link somewhere like "Having trouble with authentication?" Find something like that and go through account recovery. Then remove SMS from your account and use an authenticator app or hardware key. SMS authentication is not secure, so Amazon has deprecated it and will eventually remove it.

Comment: I didn't even know SMS was an option, I've been using authenticator apps with AWS for years.

Comment: @Tim I don't think you can set it up at all at this point, though existing accounts that set it up long ago still have it.